Consolidating Source Code from Multiple KMP Libraries into a Single Source Jar
I have two KMP libraries in one project, and I want to have one jar/lib with all source code from both libs/modules.
I added second one to first one:
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api(project(":second_kpm_lib"))
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }

And when I'm building .jar for this first lib, source code from secon is not included in it.
What I should do to make it work?

It looks like it works out of the box. We just need to release both libraries.

Add maven-publish plugin to both build.gradle in both modules

plugins {
    ...
    id("maven-publish")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        ...
        publishAllLibraryVariants()
    }


And release them ./gradlew publisToMavenLocal (add mavenLocal() if you will use local repository) or to some remote maven repository.
Add implement("your.group:first_kmp_lib:VERSION") in your actual project and both libs (first_kmp_lib and second_kmp_lib) will be added.

